# How do you count misspelled fields using a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL database that I am querying as part of a project - I only have read access to it.

There is a column called `ResultStatus` - possible values are "Passed" and "Failed". However, there were some typos by the original data inputter so some of them say "Fialed" as well. 
I want to count the number of "Failed" entries, but I want to include the "Fialed" ones as well.

```
SELECT 
        ResultStatus, Count(*)
        FROM 
            [DB_018].[dbo].[ProjectData]

        GROUP BY ResultStatus
```

is obviously grouping "Fialed" in a different category. I want it to be counted along with "Failed".

Comment: And see kids... this is why if you have a column that is a boolean, you use a bit or tinyint if you are a future proofing type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can correct the spelling yourself

```
SELECT Case When ResultStatus = 'Fialed' then 'Failed' Else ResultStatus End AS ResultStatus, Count(*)
FROM  [DB_018].[dbo].[ProjectData]
GROUP BY Case When ResultStatus = 'Fialed' then 'Failed' Else ResultStatus End
```

What this is doing is replacing the incorrect spelling with the correct one while you group the data.

Note that this is possible, and possibly cleaner, to do using a CTE

```
with CleanedResults as (
  select
    case 
      when ResultStatus = 'Fialed' then 'Failed' 
      when ResultStatus = 'Pased' then 'Passed' 
      else ResultStatus
    end as ResultStatus
  from [DB_018].[dbo].[ProjectData]
) select
  ResultStatus
, count(*) as NumResults
from CleanedResults
group by ResultStatus
```

Comment: @Michelle, generally I like Raj's approach but if you want to have maximum confidence that you're accounting for all misspellings you could find all the variations of the words in that column with e.g. `select distinct ResultStatus from DB_018.dbo.ProjectData order by 1`. Might save you time later.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
SELECT 
        case when left(ResultStatus,1) = 'P' then 'Pass' 
        when left(ResultStatus,1) = 'a' then 'audit'
        else 'fail' end as result, Count(*)
        FROM 
            ProjectData
        GROUP BY left(ResultStatus,1)
```

Comment: Beth, what happens when there is an `'Absent'` status?

Comment: updated.  the point is to reduce your dependency on accurate free-form text data entry to the first letter instead of the whole word

Answer (score 0):

as COUNT will not really count NULL values, then you can use CASE statement and just writes as below:

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN ResultStatus = 'Fialed' THEN 1
          END) as MissSpelledFailed,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ResultStatus = 'Pased' THEN 1
          END) as MisSpelledPassed,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ResultStatus = 'Failed' THEN 1
          END) as CorrectSpelledFailed,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ResultStatus = 'Passed' THEN 1
          END) as CorrectSpelledPassed,
    FROM    [DB_018].[dbo].[ProjectData]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a distinct list of ResultStatus and add them all to the case statement below. I prefer this method to Raj's as you don't need to use a CTE (not available in all version of SQL Server) or adjusting the group by.

```
SELECT
    ResultStatus,count(*) [Count]
FROM(
    SELECT 
        CASE
            WHEN ResultStatus = 'FIAL' THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN ResultStatus = 'FAIL' THEN 'FAIL'
            WHEN ResultStatus = 'Passed' THEN 'Passed'
        END [ResultStatus]
    FROM [DB_018].[dbo].[ProjectData]
)a
GROUP BY ResultStatus
```